# Use batched finder for large data query with index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing

i was working with some code optimization and i have found batched finder. But i want to know how to use batch finder with index

I mean, this is what i want to do

```
User.find_each_with_index do |user, i|
```

But this is not working

Can anyone suggest me perfect syntax for this.

Thanks

**Reference**

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/52-use-batched-finder-for-large-data-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there isn't a find_each method that includes an index, but you can simulate the behavior pretty easily:

```
i = 0
User.find_each do |user|
  ...
  i = i+1
end
```

That will give you an incrementing index for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I know this. This is manual way way to do this. Please suggest me the **Ruby way** to do this

Comment: That is the 'Ruby' way to do this.  each_with_index is a specific method on Enumerable.  The batched finder methods don't yield an Enumerable.

Comment: You mean with_index is not possible in batched finder..?

Comment: You can't just add 'with_index' to the method name.  each_with_index is a specific method on Enumerable - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index .  Batched finders don't produce Enumerables - they lazily process elements.  That's the whole point of batched finders.  So no, you can't use each_with_index with batched finders.

Answer (score -1):

There is no 'find_each_with_index' if you want to access the hash or array with index try this one.

```
User.each_with_index do |user, i|
   ......
   puts "#{user} is a data"
   puts "#{i} is a index"
end
```

Comment: You first check question carefully and go through link i have given